# How to bind C-k to kill-region if region selected; else  kill-line

Tags: emacs

In emacs, I want to bind C-k to kill-region if region selected; else kill-line as normal.
How to configure it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put this in your .emacs

```
(defun kill-line-or-region () 
 "kill region if active only or kill line normally"
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (call-interactively 'kill-region)
    (call-interactively 'kill-line)))

  (global-set-key (kbd "C-k") 'kill-line-or-region)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you first open a file and the mark is never set.

Comment: OK, the solution is to just not use `(interactive "r")`, but just `(interactive)`. I'll edit your answer.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a job for advice!

```
(defadvice kill-line (around kill-region-if-active activate)
  (if (and (called-interactively-p) (region-active-p))
      (kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    ad-do-it))
```

EDIT: Added `called-interactively-p` check.

Comment: Woooo! Hold it! `kill-line` is a functions lots of package use internally, this will change how they behave, in ways really subtle. I'd put my money on @kindahero solution, as it will do what you asked without the nasty side effects.

Comment: OK, so how about if I add a check for interactiveness, as added above?

Comment: It's a lot better, as it reduces the risk of side effects. However, I don't think `defadvice` is the right tool for the job. Over the years I've used it a lot, but I try to use it only when it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Lindydancer as I read your second comment., 1) is it correct to assume that all the hooks provided by emacs every where are for some way to avoid advising functions? 2) does advising has any effect on debugging.?

Comment: @kindahero, the hooks are natural placed where the user, or other packages, can insert extra code in a controlled fashion. You could say that the same could be done using `defadvice`, but I thing that would have led to kind of wild-west situation. Debugging is not really affected, you can single-step both the original function and the adviced code, however you must manually instrument both for debugging.

Comment: @Lindydancer Thanks for explaining. I think I understood what you have said. may be little bit of experience with writing lisp would make the picture more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a direct answer but rather some hints.

You could enable [delete-selection-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeleteSelectionMode) with `(delete-selection-mode 1)`. Then if a region is marked, when you start typing some text the region will be deleted. But in your case you could simply use <kbd>C-w</kbd> to cut the current region, this will add the region to the kill-ring but `kill-line` will do it too.